# how can I get smaller scale in RAND function

Tags: c++, c

I use this code to create random number between zero and 1.

```
randnumber = (double)((double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX);
```

This line of code regularly give me numbers like 0.650434, 0.302340 and 0.906789 which are big numbers for me. The problem is I need smaller range number like these numbers: 0.000200, 0.000100, 0.000400, 0.000600 and so on.
how can I modify this line of code to get my result?

Comment: Could you not just random from 1-100 and then divide each number by 10000?  (Or whatever scale factor you need)?  I don't see a need to do the division within the random function.

Comment: Use [`std::uniform_real_distribution<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution).

Comment: Which are you using, C or C++?

Comment: divide by ten for range [ 0 0.1]

Comment: @rightfold If he wants `[0,1)` then [std::generate_canonical](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/generate_canonical) is better.

Comment: You have casting overkill, consider just `randnumber = (double)rand()/RAND_MAX` (equivalent to `randnumber = ((double)rand())/RAND_MAX` due to operator precedence which is equivalent to what you've got due to [variables promotion](http://icecube.wisc.edu/~dglo/c_class/promo_conv.html)).

Comment: there in no differences between c or c++ for me

Comment: Is `0.0002568968931` also fine? Meaning the number must be < `0.0010`, or do you want a number in the form `0.000x00` where x is some digit?

Comment: @Dukeling: Actually OP's final cast is not a no-op. It throws away excess precision leftover from the division. I don't claim OP used it this was intentionally, but it's worth noting.

Comment: @R.. Can you elaborate? As far as I'm aware, `(double)rand()/RAND_MAX` returns a `double`, thus `(double)((double)rand()/RAND_MAX)` casts a `double` to a `double`, thus doesn't do anything. Or by "final" do you mean "right-most"? In which case, to my knowledge, `RAND_MAX` will get promoted to `double` before the multiplication without an explicit cast, thus the cast isn't necessary.

Comment: @Dukeling: I mean the leftmost. See C99 6.3.1.8 *The values of floating operands and of the results of floating expressions may be represented in greater precision and range than that required by the type; the types are not changed thereby.* ...

Comment: ... and 6.3.1.5 *When a double is demoted to float, a long double is demoted to double or float, or a value being represented in greater precision and range than required by its semantic type (see 6.3.1.8) is explicitly converted (including to its own type), if the value being converted can be represented exactly in the new type, it is unchanged. If the value being converted is in the range of values that can be represented but cannot be represented exactly, the result is either the nearest higher or nearest lower representable value, chosen in an implementation-defined manner.*

Answer (score 3):

Do you know what kind of probability distribution function you're looking for?  If you still want uniform you can simply divide the [0,1) result by a large number and apply a shift so that it's centered around the value you want.

If you want something that's normally distributed you can use something like the inverse transform [method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling).  Again you'll need to center it and modify the standard deviation. There are similar transformations to other distributions as well

Comment: could you tell me more about inverse transform sampling and the way of implementing that

Comment: In order to help you I need to know what kind of distribution you're trying to get to.  If you're trying to get to a normal distribution the Box-Muller transform is easy to implement and not terribly slow (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-Muller_transform <- See Basic Form)

Comment: you know I have this probability function: probability =((x -2) / 10000 ) and want to create a random number by the rand() function between zero and 1. Then compare random number with probability. If the the random number is less than probability do some thing.  the problem is the distribution of randnumber is not adaptive with the distribution of probability function.

Comment: Is x a random variable that produces a value on the range [0,1)?  If so what's your problem?

Comment: no x is a number between 2 and 10000

Answer (score 1):

This gives random number between 1 and 100

```
int randInt= (rand()%100)+1;
```

so divide it, to get your desired range

```
double yourRange=(double)randInt/100000;
```

Comment: It gives a non-uniform result distribution and also happens to have very poor entropy on some implementations.